# sudo -su: Command not found

Tags: bash, sudo, zsh

I'm doing this in a `.sh` script which I'm calling like this `sudo ./script.sh`:

```
user=${SUDO_USER} # ="alex"
sudo -su ${user} node
```

Result:

```
/bin/bash: node: command not found
```

Same goes for other commands like `yarn` or `nvm` also all are installed and working when being logged in as `alex`

What am I doing wrong?

`which node` run as `alex` returns this:

```
/home/alex/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/bin/node
```

`node` for `alex` is installed using `nvm` which adds this to the end of `/home/alex/.zshrc` (`alex` is using `zsh`)

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're doing a bit more? What user are you starting as? Why do `sudo -i` and then `sudo -su alex`? Why not just `sudo -u alex node` or `sudo -iu alex; node` etc? If you explain what the objective and the constraints you are working under are (e.g. I need to run command A as Bob and command B as Alex), we should be able to help.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: yeah sounds iffy, what kind of script doesn't know the sudo user yet wants root priveleges?

Comment: try `sudo -E`, that should preserve the environment. By the `sudo -su user command` is very strange...

Comment: @SimonSudler still the same result

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341258/how-can-i-preserve-an-environment-variable-across-su

Comment: You need to preserve the environment over `sudo` and `su`. Go with the suggestion from @terdon. `sudo -Eu alex node`

Comment: @SimonSudler still no luck

Comment: Is there a better way to acchieve this: The script has to solve several things like creating a self signed cert (which requires `sudo`) and also start `node` commands like `yarn` (which don't require `sudo` at all)

Comment: Can you add the output of  `sudo -E -u alex which node` to your question?

Comment: There's no output for `sudo -E -u alex which node`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94768/discussion-between-simon-sudler-and-alexander-zeitler).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no user named node. try this

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep node
```

if it prints node, this works

```
user=${SUDO_USER} 
sudo -su ${user} node
```

if not create user named node, sth like this

```
adduser node
user=${SUDO_USER} 
sudo -su ${user} node
```

and finally your scripts.sh will work.

Comment: `sudo -su $user node` is short for `sudo -s -u $user node`. The intention is to run the _command_ `node` as user `$user` while having a proper environment. There is no point in creating a user `node`.